# How many users can be added to a MS Dynamics 365 Team?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

Theoretically I'm sure there is probably no limit, but realistically I'm looking to understand how many users can be added into a MS Dynamics 365 Team. I'd like to understand what impact adding more than 8,000 users to a single team would have in terms of performance of the Dynamics application.

Why so many users in a team? We're looking at a potential requirement, which needs to secure 4 fields on an entity so that users can create those fields but not view the data in them. Short Answer: Field Level Security. However, we have a large user base ie. 8,000 users and once we create a field security profile, we need to assign that profile to 8,000 users. So an idea was to create a Team and assign the field security profile to the team. Then add 8000 users into that team.

So back to my original question. Is this a plausible solution and is there anything we're overlooking in going ahead with this. Would we face performance issues going forward? Is there a better/alternate solution to meet the requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 8k users + team + FLS scenario should not be a problem, as I remember from [this performance benchmark](https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/6/6/D66E61BA-3D18-49E8-B042-8434E64FAFCA/PerformanceBenchmarkforCRMOnline2016Update1.pdf) (on online CRM 2016 update 1 though. ie v8.1), the testing was performed and gave better results with below configuration to prove statistically.

> Field-level security was also enabled on custom attributes to reflect
> a realistic enterprise organization.
>
> Based on customer research, each user of a specific role was assigned
> a realistic set of data. The data that the user would own was based on
> the user’s role. Before the test, the total data in the test database
> included more than 656,549,587 business records with a total database
> size of 1.024 TB.
>
> TeamMembership with 61,406 records.
>
> A batch of 17,868 concurrent users performed create, update, and
> delete (CRUD) operations within Dynamics CRM Online.